# Check Equality of Multiple Columns in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

```
data = [[10,10,10],[12,12,12],[10,12,10]]
df = DataFrame(data,columns=['Col1','Col2','Col3'])
df
   Col1 Col2 Col3
0   10   10   10
1   12   12   12
2   10   12   10
```

I need something that would return - True, True, False.

This was an example. My data has 20 columns that need this check.
How can I do it?

Comment: Yes. It is a duplicate. Thanks